# how to add constructors parameter to a list?

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I got a list of classes called classList. Each class in this list has a constructor with a string parameter that contains some info about the class. I want to iterate through the classList and then add all the constructor parameters to a stringarray.
How can I do this?

```
public Main()
    {
        classList = new List<class>();
        class1 = new class1("class1 information");
        class2 = new class2("class2 information");
        classList.Add(class1);
        classList.Add(class2);
    }

public void getConstructorParametersToList()
    {
        string[] myArrayList = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < classList.Count; i++)
        {
            //Add the parameters from the constructors to a string array
            myArrayList[i] = parameterfromconstructor
        }
    }

public void doSomething()
    {
        foreach (string s in myArrayList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
//Output:
//Class1 information
//Class2 information
```

Comment: Include your code in question

Comment: OP: Can you include some example code for the constructor where it is shown how the constructor looks like and also for how the function is called/should be calleD?

Comment: Question is really unclear. You want to add the name of the parameters or the value? If latter answer is no, not possible. Post some code to clarify your question with the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store that constructor parameter in class field or property and later access it.

```
public interface IParameterizedClass
{
   string ClassParameter {get}
}

public class class1 : IParameterizedClass
{
   public string ClassParameter {get; private set;}
   public class1(string someParameter)
   {
     // do some work

     ClassParameter = someParameter;
   }
}  

public class class2 : IParameterizedClass
{
   public string ClassParameter {get; private set;}
   public class2(string someParameter)
   {
     // do some work

     ClassParameter = someParameter;
   }
}

public void getConstructorParametersToList()
{
    string[] myArrayList = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < classList.Count; i++)
    {
        //Add the parameters from the constructors to a string array
        myArrayList[i] = (classList[i] as IParameterizedClass).ClassParameter;
    }
}
```